# How can I create a script that can turn pictures into 2D low poly images?

Tags: scripting, image

Before: [image]

http://cdn1.digitalartsonline.co.uk/cmsdata/slideshow/3513552/DAT_004.jpg

After:

[image]

https://m1.behance.net/rendition/modules/113025095/disp/9db2282a74ec5c6e7f48aeb0f9421e3f.jpg

Does anyone have ideas on how I would do this?

Comment: If this is possible its way outside the scope of something that could be answered here.  In the image you provided it looks like each triangle was positioned by hand.  The details around the nose and ears are more detailed than the hair or cheeks as an example.  That isn't something that could be automated without some really advanced image recognition.  However if you simply are looking to automatically color an existing mesh thats probably doable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll still have to place the geometry by hand, but I've put together a simple material that will automatically set the colors for you.  For this example I've used a triangulated, subdivided plane.  Its not a bad result, but it does look a bit dry and grid like.

[image]

In order for this to work each triangle should be its own object with its its origin at its center.  To do this quickly you could create your triangles as a single mesh object and then in edit mode press <kbd>crtl</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> and choose "edge split".  You would then need to press <kbd>p</kbd> -> "separate by loose parts", after which you would exit edit mode and do a <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> -> "set origin to geometry".

Input image:
[image]

Output:

[image]

Update: Here's what my sample looks like after applying @3pointedit's suggestion

[image]

Comment: In addition to this I would drive a displacement of the geometry (vertically) with the source image then unsubdivide based on angle.

Comment: @3pointedit Thats a really clever idea

Comment: Yeah I accidentally did it a while ago, have a look https://twitter.com/3pointedit/status/733176875804057600